# Base CRM Rails Gem legacy search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

It looks like Base CRM has upgraded their API and replaced all of their endpoints/parameters.

Previously I was able to retrieve "Won" deals using this call:

```
session = BaseCrm::Session.new("<LEGACY_ACCESS_TOKEN>")
session.deals.all(stage: :won, sort_by: :last_activity, sort_order: :desc, page: 1)
```

This query recently started ignoring my parameters, yet it continued to respond with unfiltered data (that was fun when I realized that was happening).

The new syntax is:

```
client = BaseCRM::Client.new(access_token: "<YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>")
client.deals.where(organization_id: google.id, hot: true)
```

yet this does not work:

```
client.deals.where(stage_name: :won)
client.deals.where(stage_name: "Won")
client.deals.where(stage_id: 8) # specified ID found in Base Docs for "Won"
```

etc.

I've looked into the most recent updates to the [Base CRM Gem](https://github.com/basecrm/basecrm-ruby) as well as the [Base CRM API Docs](https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/reference/deals) but have not found a solution to searching by specific deal stage.

Has anyone had any luck with the new API and this kind of query?
Is there a way to use the legacy API?

I've left message with Base but I really need to fix this, you know, yesterday.

Thanks for your help!

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

The legacy API/gem responded with JSON where the v2 API/gem responds with a `BaseCRM::Deal` object:

```
$ session.deals.find(123456)
# <BaseCRM::Deal 
   dropbox_email="dropbox@67890.deals.futuresimple.com",
   name="Cool Deal Name", 
   owner_id=54321, 
   creator_id=65432, 
   value=2500, 
   estimated_close_date=nil, 
   last_activity_at="2016-04-21T02:29:43Z", 
   tags=[], 
   stage_id=84588, 
   contact_id=098765432, 
   custom_fields={:"Event Location"=>"New York, NY", :Source=>"Friend"},         
   last_stage_change_at="2016-04-21T02:08:20Z", 
   last_stage_change_by_id=559951, 
   created_at="2016-04-18T22:16:35Z", 
   id=123456, 
   updated_at="2016-04-21T02:08:20Z", 
   organization_id=nil, 
   hot=false, 
   currency="USD", 
   source_id=1466480, 
   loss_reason_id=nil
   >
```

Checkout `stage_id`. Is this a bug? According to the Docs `stage_id` should return an integer between 1 and 10.

Comment: my current workaround is `session.deals.find_all(per_page: 50, sort_by: :updated_at, page: 1).select{ |hash| hash["stage_name"] == "Won" }` which eager loads with deals with all stages and filters on my side (not preferable).

Comment: Have you tried to first find the stage id of the stage you're interested in (https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/reference/stages) then call deals endpoint (https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/reference/deals) with stage_id=.. query parameter? It might not be "8" anymore.

Comment: @mabn thanks for your response. It is 8 according to the most recent docs.